# What is the kind of polymorphic/polykinded tuples?

Tags: haskell, type-families, polykinds

While I was going through the [haskell-excercises](https://github.com/i-am-tom/haskell-exercises/blob/answers/08-PolyKinds/src/Exercises.hs#L22) questions. I saw the following code which creates an aggregate `Constraint` by applying each type to a Constraint constructor. In GHC it seems deeply nested tuples of `Constraint`s are still of kind `Constraint` (perhaps flattened ?).

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}


type family All (c :: Type -> Constraint) (xs :: [Type]) :: Constraint where
  All c '[] = ()
  All c (x ': xs) = (c x, All c xs)

-- >>> :kind! All
-- All :: (* -> Constraint) -> [*] -> Constraint
-- = All

-- >>> :kind! All Eq '[Int, Double, Float]
-- All Eq '[Int, Double, Float] :: Constraint
-- = (Eq Int, (Eq Double, (Eq Float, () :: Constraint)))
```

I tried to generalize it using `PolyKinds` extension as following.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}


type family All' (c :: k -> r) (xs :: [k]) :: r where
  All' c '[] = ()
  All' c (x ': xs) = (c x, All' c xs)

-- >>> :kind! All'
-- All' :: (k -> r) -> [k] -> r
-- = All'

--- This one works. Tuples of Types is a Type.
-- >>> :kind! All' Maybe '[Int, Double, Float]
-- All' Maybe '[Int, Double, Float] :: *
-- = (Maybe Int, (Maybe Double, (Maybe Float, ())))

--- However this one gets stuck.
-- >>> :kind! All' Eq '[Int, Double, Float]
-- All' Eq '[Int, Double, Float] :: Constraint
-- = All' Eq '[Int, Double, Float]
```

Is the kind of `'(,) (a :: k) (b :: k)` also of kind `k`. Looking below it doesn't seems so, so I wonder why the type family definition `All' c (x ': xs) = (c x, All' c xs)` was accepted in the first place (considering the type family return kind was `r`)?

```
λ> :kind! '(,)
'(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)
= '(,)

λ> :kind! '(,) ('True :: Bool) ('False :: Bool)
'(,) ('True :: Bool) ('False :: Bool) :: (Bool, Bool)
= '( 'True, 'False)
```

**UPDATE**

As @Daniel Wagner already mentioned below the `(,)` used here is considered as `Type -> Type -> Type` and the kind parameter `r` is instantiated to `Type` within the second equation above (`All' c (x ': xs) = (c x, All' c xs)`). In fact if we had used `'(,)`, it would have correctly returned a type error. I was able to further confirm it using a technique [described in this blog post](https://ryanglscott.github.io/2019/05/26/on-the-arity-of-type-families/) as following (`All'` is instantiated with kinds `k`, and `*`):

```
λ> :set -fprint-explicit-kinds
λ> :info All'
type All' :: forall k r. (k -> r) -> [k] -> r
type family All' @k @r c xs where
  forall k (c :: k -> *). All' @k @(*) c ('[] @k) = ()
  forall k (c :: k -> *) (x :: k) (xs :: [k]).
    All' @k @(*) c ((':) @k x xs) = (c x, All' @k @(*) c xs)
```

Comment: N.B. the `All'` definition in your update at the end does *not* match the `All` definition at the beginning of the original question! The original one has a `Constraint` kind annotation that the one at the end lacks.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, my bad. There was a typo, the original question was actually about `All'` (the one using `PolyKinds`).

Comment: Huh. Reading your `All'` definition more carefully, I actually find it very odd that the compiler accepts it. You demand `All' _ _ :: r`, but then define `All' _ '[] = ()`, and there's no good reason to believe `() :: r`. Could this be a GHC bug?

Comment: Indeed, GHC 9.2 does not accept your definition of `All'`! Either definition on its own is rejected (i.e. just `All' c '[] = ()` or just `All' c (x ': xs) = (c x, All' c xs)`), as seems like ought to happen. I suspect you have simply stumbled over a bug here.

Comment: Yes, that was basically my question. I was surprised that GHC didn't give a type error. Also as written in the "UPDATE", it seems `r` is always instantiated `Type`, so probably that is why it type-checks. I haven't check with GHC 9.2 yet.

Comment: @DanielWagner, it doesn't sound like a bug to me. It's implicitly matching on the return kind. Why doesn't 9.2 accept that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a syntactic pun here. There are actually several different commas, with differing kinds:

```
 (,) :: Type -> Type -> Type
 (,) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constraint -- ...ish
'(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)
```

Note that none of these kinds unify with any other. Additionally, the second one is a bit of a lie; if `x :: Constraint` and `y :: Constraint`, then `(x, y) :: Constraint`, but the comma cannot be put prefix as in `(,) x y`.

When attempting to disambiguate the first two, GHC assumes you are using `(,) :: Type -> Type -> Type` unless you are in a place which syntactically cannot use that (e.g. to the left of an `=>`) or you have given an explicit kind annotation of `:: Constraint`. The single-tick `'` disambiguates between the first two and the last one.

Comment: I expect if the early Haskell committee had foreseen that we would have `DataKinds` at some point, they would have ditched the `(Num a, Eq a)` notation and it would instead maybe be `(&) :: Constraint -> Constraint -> Constrained` or something.

Comment: Thanks that clears up the confusion, I updated the question with that observation. I guess if we want to have a generic `All` type-level function, it should have separate equations for each `Type`, `Constraint`, and kind `k` (and having a new kind variable for the return kind)?